# Transformation Representation on 2 basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, change-of-basis

Condition:

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear operator defined by,
$$
T\left ( \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\
\end{bmatrix} \right ) = \begin{bmatrix}
x+y\\ 
-2x+4y\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Also, let $B_1 = \begin{Bmatrix}
e_1, & e_2
\end{Bmatrix}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $B_2 = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\
\end{bmatrix}, &
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}$ be a second basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The solution says:
$$[T]_{B_1} = \begin{Bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-2 & 4 \\
\end{Bmatrix}, 
[T]_{B_2} = \begin{Bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 3 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Though I could easily calculate $[T]_{B_1}$, by getting $T(e_1$) and $T(e_2$),

I don't have any idea how $[T]_{B_2}$ is calculated. Can't it be calculated through just inputting basis in $B_2$ to the Transformation matrix?

Thank you.

Comment: you can write the same more clear with this simple notation: $T(x,y)=(x+y,-2x+4y)$ because a linear operator is not a matrix, however it can be represented by the algebra of matrix multiplication. Then you can write $\mathcal M(T)$ or just $[T]$ to represent $T$ as a matrix choosing some basis of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}3\\6\end{bmatrix}=3\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}.$$That's why the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B_2$ is the one that you mentioned.

Comment: Real thanks. I terribly missed the concept.